# Error while rake db:seed, prefilling database. uninitialized constant Clients_courses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I want to prefill my database with the db/seeds.rb but got an error during execution.

The schema is loaded and setup perfectly. But when I will prefill the database with rake db:seed i got this error:

```
uninitialized constant Clients_courses
```

I have got the Table clients_courses in my database schema. So I've tried to prefill it like this:

```
Clients_courses.create(:client_id => 6, :course_id => 2)
```

What's wrong with this?

I've tried it with some other tables as well for example with the users table. But theres the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have corresponding model to manipulate data like this. For `users` table you usually have `User` model. In your case you either have `ClientsCourses` or `ClientsCourse` model, or, assuming you have `:has_and_belongs_to_many` association there is no such model.

And in this case, the only way to do what you want is to use existing ones(`Client` and `Course`):

```
 Client.find(6).courses << Course.find(2)
```

Comment: Additional quastion. If I do `Client.create( :id => `

The id is an autoincrement column in database. But the values I add to database need to have a special id for example it coudln't start with 1 . in this case it I need to set up a client id 2 client id 10 ... 

Is that possiblie? ... If I do `Client.create( :id => 10` it automatically set it to one

Comment: also not working is this: `:active => 1` colum is tinyint on database and every time i run rake db:seed the value is set to `0`

Comment: @Felix it is a bad idea to manipulate with primary key. Much better approach is to create new field and use it for your special purposes. Sorry, but I didn't understand your last question. I can't tell anything unless you show db scheme and code for both models.

Comment: in the table users I have an column called `active` withe datatype tinyint. so now I want to store with the seeds.rb int values `User.create([
                {
                    :id => 1,
                    :firstname => 'Felix',
                    :lastname => 'Hohlwegler', :active => 1}]) ` but it dosn't store 1. It always stores 0 in database.

Comment: @Felix this is unrelated to initial question, but try this: `User.create({ :id => 1, :firstname => 'Felix', :lastname => 'Hohlwegler', :active => true })`

Comment: yeah I know its a different question. I've started a new question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29266317/problems-during-rake-dbseed-value-dosnt-set-correctly

Comment: this: `Client.find(6).courses << Course.find(2)` is a n:m relationship right? ... how can I realize a 1:n relationship?

Answer (score 1):

- Create a model  ClientsCourse
  ie in app/model/clients_course.rb
- Inside the file add line below and save

  ```
  class ClientsCourse   < ActiveRecord::Base

  end
  ```
- Correct the line as below

  ```
   ClientsCourse.create(:client_id => 6, :course_id => 2)
  ```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

your model name **should** be `client_course.rb` and a table named `client_courses`