# Problems during rake db:seed, value dosn't set correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I want to prefill my table with the seeds.rb file in app/db

but there I got a problem during storing the right data.

in the table users I have an column called active withe datatype tinyint. so now I want to store with the seeds.rb int values

```
User.create([ { :id => 1, :firstname => 'Felix', :lastname => 'Hohlwegler', :active => 1}])
```

but it dosn't store 1. It always stores 0 in database.

also tried this:

```
User.create([ { :id => 1, :firstname => 'Felix', :lastname => 'Hohlwegler', :active => true}])
```

same problem it stores 0 in db.

Whats going wrong?

Comment: Why not leave the ID field blank since Rails auto-creates/increments id's? Just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common thing that causes this kind of problems are validations. In this case I would expect that a user needs an email or a password. Please check if

```
User.create!(
  :id => 1, :firstname => 'Felix', :lastname => 'Hohlwegler', :active => true
)
```

passes the validations and creates an user.

Please note that I use `create!` that would raise an error if it not able to create an user instead of just returning an unsaved one.

Answer (score 0):

solution that works fine for me:

```
u = User.new(
  :id => 1, :firstname => 'Felix', :lastname => 'Hohlwegler', :active => 1
)

u.active = true
u.save
```